# How to resolve SequelizeDatabaseError NaN when using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sqlite, pagination, sequelize.js

I am getting this error when running a simple sequelize.js query for my model.

```
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Books` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, `title` VARCHAR(255), `author` VARCHAR(255), `genre` VARCHAR(255), `first_published` INTEGER);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`Books`)
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_INFO(`sqlite_autoindex_books_1`)
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Patrons` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, `first_name` VARCHAR(255), `last_name` VARCHAR(255), `address` VARCHAR(255), `email` VARCHAR(255), `library_id` VARCHAR(255), `zip_code` INTEGER);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`Patrons`)
Executing (default): SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM `Books` AS `Book`;
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `author`, `genre`, `first_published` FROM `Books` AS `Book` ORDER BY `Book`.`title` LIMIT 0, 4;
GET /1 304 410.149 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1.446 ms - -
Executing (default): SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM `Books` AS `Book`;
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `author`, `genre`, `first_published` FROM `Books` AS `Book` ORDER BY `Book`.`title` LIMIT NaN, 4;
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: NaN
    at Query.formatError (C:\Users\user\Downloads\Sandbox\10\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:423:16)
    at afterExecute (C:\Users\user\Downloads\Sandbox\10\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:119:32)
    at replacement (C:\Users\user\Downloads\Sandbox\10\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\trace.js:19:31)
    at Statement.errBack (C:\Users\user\Downloads\Sandbox\10\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:16:21)
```

The funny thing is the code works fine, its just the console is spitting the above error out everytime the route is hit.

I basically have a simple route using express router that takes in an id param. I then use the id param to calculate some values for LIMIT and OFFSET to use in my pagination.

It seems to me that the query is being executed twice, the second time the offset is NaN

First execution:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `author`, `genre`, `first_published` FROM `Books` AS `Book` ORDER BY `Book`.`title` LIMIT 0, 4;
```

Second execution:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `author`, `genre`, `first_published` FROM `Books` AS `Book` ORDER BY `Book`.`title` LIMIT NaN, 4;
```

This is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Book = require('../models').Book;


router.get('/:page', function (req, res, next) {
    Book.findAndCountAll({
        order: [ ['title'] ],
        offset: ((req.params.page - 1) * 4),
        limit: 4
    }).then(function (book) {
        let pages = Math.ceil(book.count / 4);
        res.render('index', {
            content: book.rows,
            pagination: pages,
            title: 'Express'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: can you post what is the value of `req.params.page` for both the requests?

Answer (score 2):

Cast `req.params.page` to `number` using something like this: `+req.params.page` before subtracting and multiplication. By default `params` object contains `string` values ([API](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)).

Comment: That did it, also I ended up doing 2 extra steps. I added a catch() and fixed the favicon error.